# Health incorrectly shows the same wake up time everyday

Tags: iphone, sleep-wake, apple-watch, health.app

I noticed that even when I don’t wear my watch to bed, the time I go to bed is remarkably accurate in the Health app—even on days I don’t wear my watch to bed.

However, the same is not true about the time I wake up. Instead of it being accurate, it shows the same wake up time every day, 6am.

I have Sleep schedule enabled since I want rough reminders of when to go to bed/wind down. However, I turned off the wake up alarm.

I noticed that the time Health shows that I woke up everyday is exactly the same time as the wake up alarm, 6am. This is inaccurate since most days I wake up after 6am.

How do I fix the wake up time tracked by my phone/watch so that my health data isn’t all messed up?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works but could be worth trying:

1. In your sleep schedule activate "Use Schedule for Sleep Focus" so the sleep focus gets activated when you go to sleep
2. Before going to sleep in the Clock app go to alarm, find "Sleep|Wake Up" and click on "Change"
3. Leave alarm turned off if you don't want an alarm
4. Set the wake up time to way later than you will wake up
5. Sleep
6. When waking up deactivate the sleep focus or activate another focus

This could save the time when you deactivate the sleep focus as your wake up time.

Comment: The "Sleep" step made me laugh haha